# Issue finding and replacing regex in Powershell

Tags: string, powershell, replace

I have an ini file that looks like this:

```
[list_text]                       
text_002=L-Win+3=Regards\nThomas
```

I try to find and replace the "\nThomas" with a different name:

```
$settings = Get-Content -Raw $path -Encoding UTF8
$settings = $settings -replace '`r`nThomas', '\nMike'
```

I tested different ways trying to find the "\nThomas" but nothing seems to work.

Comment: You're looking for a literal ```\```: `-replace '\\nThomas', '\nMike'`

Comment: thanks it is working! If you paste this as answer I can mark it correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern `` "`r`n..." `` will look for a literal carriage return and newline characters.

You aren't looking for any of those, you're looking for the verbatim escape sequence `\n`. To describe a backslash in a regex pattern, escape it with another backslash:

```
$settings -replace '\\nThomas', '\nMike'
```

You can also use `[regex]::Escape()` to escape any given verbatim string:

```
$settings -replace ([regex]::Escape('\nThomas')), '\nMike'
```